# Is there a way to get O(1) without extra space in the union find algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures

Is there a way to get O(1) without extra space in the union find algorithm?

Imagine I have 3 sets

```
set1 = {1, 3, 5, 7}
set2 = {4,20,25}
set3 = {9, 13}
```

Now imagine I have a new edge between 3 and 20. So I would need to merge set1 and set2, but before I do that I need find which set 3 belongs to and which set 20 belongs to. So how can I get an O(1) find operation to find the set the element belongs to without extra space?

With extra space I can easily store each node and its corresponding set in a hashmap.

Comment: It still uses extra space, but you can probably just use array instead of hashmap.
Also: note that in your extra-memory solution, you will need to use small-to-large trick so Union runs in O(logn).
I don't think it's possible to do Find in O(1) without extra memory. If you try to replace the parent array with a "corresponding set" array, you still need a vector for each root to store what is in the set, which is O(n) extra memory.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can make Find run in $O(1)$ time if you allow Union to run in $O(n)$ time.

Suppose the elements are numbered $0,1,\dots,n-1$.  We'll maintain an array $A[0..n-1]$, where $A[i]$ is the set that contains element $i$.  Then a Find operation takes $O(1)$ time, since it consists solely of looking up in the array.  A Union operation can be done in $O(n)$ time by scanning through $A$ to find all elements of both sets and updating the array so that they're both contained in the same set.  Notice that this doesn't use any additional space.

You can replace the array with a hashtable if you prefer, and that will allow items to be identified by arbitrary identifiers (instead of integers $0..n-1$).

This probably isn't useful in practice unless Union operations are extremely rare, because the Union operation becomes so expensive.  In most situations it will probably be preferable to use a standard Union-Find data structure or extra space.